# Prove or give counterexample of ba=ac implies b=c

Tags: group-theory

Let (G,°) be a group with the neutral element e (not necessarily abelian) . a,b,c are random elements of G.

Statement: ba=ac implies b=c

Prove or give counterexample!

I really believe there must be a counterexample, but i can't find one. Please help!!^^ Thx

Comment: There are counterexamples in literally the smallest non-abelian group....

Comment: Hint: If $G$ were abelian, then we could rewrite $ba=ac$ as $ba=ca$, then cancel the $a$'s to get $b=c$.

Comment: and what if G is definitely not abelian? is there a good counterexample?

Comment: @mojo At that point, maybe *you* should try to find one?

Comment: In **every** nonabelian group, you can find a counterexample.  How hard can it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is not abelian.

Choose any pair of elements $a,b \in G$ such that $ab \ne ba$, and let $c=a^{-1}ba$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&a^{-1}ba = c\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a(a^{-1}ba) = ac\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(a(a^{-1}))ba = ac\\[4pt]
\implies\;&ba = ac\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
But we can't have $c=b$, else $ba = ac$ would imply $ba = ab$.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest non-abelian group is $S_3$. Take $a=(1\ 2)$ and $c=(1\ 3)$. Then$$aca^{-1}=aca=(1\ 2)(1\ 3)(1\ 2)=(2\ 3).$$So, take $b=(2\ 3)$. Then $b=aca^{-1}$, and this means that $ba=ac$.

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's a precise, succinct answer that shows how to generalize and create more counterexamples.

Comment: @Randall I suspect that the downvote came from someone who thinks that the question did not deserve an answer. I am not sure about that myself.

Comment: I agree with that, but then the question should be downvoted.

Comment: @Randall Did you read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15126/is-it-appropriate-to-downvote-answers-for-the-sake-of-deleting-a-question)?

Comment: I did not give you a downvote, but sometimes, when the question looks like a homework problem and the OP does not illustrate any attempts, some users give downvotes to answers.  This is because they believe that the OP should work more and not simply be given answers.  I have had such downvotes on my answers in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a non abelian group for your counter example obviously. Look at $S_3$.

$$(13)(21) = (21)(23)$$

clearly $b \neq c$ in this example.